# /var/task/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:93 throw err0;

Tags: javascript, github, cyclic

I dont know why my website keeps saying error when trying to launch on cyclic

[image: Cyclic Error]

Comment: Hi. Please don't post screenshots of text (code, errors,etc.). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question for why it should be avoided. Also, it is very hard to answer to your question as is, since you didn't include any code that provoked that error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.